# Logout code for kibana using node js, keycloak and nginx

Tags: keycloak, kibana, openid-connect, keycloak-nodejs-connect

I am attempting to create a logout function in Node.js with Nginx also running. For example, if a user accesses the logout URL, they should be redirected to a specific URL, such as the Keycloak endpoint.

function logout(r) {

```
r.log("[START] Logging out user session and terminating OIDC session.");

// Clear the access token cookie to log out the user
r.headersOut["Set-Cookie"] = "access_token=; Max-Age=0; Path=/";

// Terminate OIDC session by redirecting to the Keycloak logout URL
var keycloakLogoutUrl = "https://keycloak.com/auth/realms/xyz/protocol/openid-connect/logout";
r.return(302, keycloakLogoutUrl);

r.log("[FINISH] Logging out user session and terminating OIDC session.");
```

}

Nginx configuration :

location /logout {
internal;  # This location is only accessible internally

Some configuration with server

}